# Linux Mint - USB Ethernet Adapter Shutting Off Under Load

Tags: linux, usb, ethernet, linux-mint

I've recently installed Linux Mint on my desktop computer. Whenever I begin download something over the internet using my TP-Link USB to Ethernet adapter, my connection shuts off after about 10 seconds. It doesn't come back until I physically reinsert the Ethernet cable into the adapter; not even restarting it in the network menu works. The adapter has been working great for over a year on Windows 10, so I assume it's not a hardware problem. The internet also works as expected when I use a Wi-Fi connection.

Things I've tried:

- Installing the Linux driver from TP-Link's website
- Updating all installed packages
- Completely reinstalling Linux Mint

I can provide more information about my system if needed.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Odd, this is a new one to me... Can you attach the output of `inxi -Nnn` to your original question and the exact model of adapter, and than I may have more questions.